# SQL объединить в одинаковые группы

Tags: sql, сортировка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день.
как в SQL запросами
Как сделать сортировку по одинаковым группам в двух столбиках.
Order by делает сортировку только по первому столбику а во втором как получится.
На картинке первый столбик от сортировался хорошо и одинаковые записи объединились.
Во втором есть записи которые улетели в разные места(указано стрелками)
Нужно эти записи тоже в группы обеднить но не вытаскивая по возможности из однородных записей первого столбика.
Подскажите способ, если знаете.

Comment: Код вашего селекта покажите в вопросе )

Comment: SELECT [1_Наконечник],[2_Наконечник]
FROM [tabl]
ORDER BY  [1_Наконечник]DESC,[2_Наконечник]DESC    (это работает только с первым столбиком, второй сортируется как Бог даст)

Comment: Добавляйте все уточнения в сам вопрос (внопка "править").

Comment: Всё правильно отсортировано. Второй столбец сортируется внутри групп первого. Как и указано в запросе.

Comment: Нужно одинаковые в обоих столбиках уложить рядом как в первом. Со стрелками записи  в группу и тд Щас со стрелками находятся далеко друг от друга

Comment: То есть вы хотите отсортировать по второму столбцу. Тогда нарушится сортировка первого.

Comment: Которые со стрелками(как пример) можно уложить поближе друг к другу и не нарушив одинаковые группы в первом столбце. Но пока в виде запроса я не знаю увк это сделать